# How do I troubleshoot screen configuration failure on a new install?

Tags: boot, system-installation, macbook-pro

I installed Ubuntu on a 2008 MacBook Pro yesterday and can't get any display or x server booted. I can boot from the CD into rescue mode, so I can see that:

- The syslog has an error, `GdmLocalDisplayFactory: maximum number of X display failures reached: check X server log for errors`
- In `/var/log/Xorg.1.log` (and the other Xorg logs) I see "Fatal server error: [27.266] (EE) no screens found(EE)"
- Earlier in the log out also says "screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section." several times. It also says "Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration."

I'm guessing there's a ... screen configuration issue? But I don't know where to start troubleshooting it.

Note: I did discover [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) which I walked through, but holding down right-shift doesn't do anything. It just lands me in a silver screen (light grey, I guess) with an arrow cursor and nothing else.

I can boot to rescue mode from the CD,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per  [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38782#38782) Boot into rescue mode, edit `/etc/default/grub` to add `nomodetest` and then do `update grub`.